# Bash - setting environment vars from bash invocation line

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm looking for a way to manipulate some env var, which will be available for processes spawned by bash.

Something like the below (of course, the syntax is not correct)

```
/bin/bash VAR_X=2
```

and then later command being run from bash script can do

```
if [ "$ENV_VAR_X" = 2 ] ..
```

Notice that I'm invoking bash from a windows Console2/Msys setup, so doing `VAR_X=2 bash` is not an option.

Does anyone know how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`env VAR_X=2 command`

This would pre-define the variable named VAR_X (only if you runs bash as current shell)

**EDIT**

To fix that on Windows system, simply create a cmd script, that set the variable prior to execution, or in My Computers->Advanced->Environment Variables set a global one,

```
@echo off
set VAR_X=2
command
```

Comment: @user1480524 see if the update hepls

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
    yourVar="your value" /bin/bash
```

then you're in bash, or running any other program, and $yourVar is *your value*

Comment: I didn't give enough info - I'm running Console2/Msys setup, so prepending the var to the bash invocation is not possible. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    export yourVar="your value"
```

will also make the variable available to subprocesses.